# unable to access variable value assigned by cookie with the instantiated object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

```
    using System.Web;
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Cookies value
    /// </summary>
    public class clsCookies
    {

        public string session { get; set; }

        private string _clientId { get; set; }
        public string clientid
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_clientId))
                {
                    _clientId = this.getValue("clientid");
                }
                return _clientId;
            }
        }

        private string _userid { get; set; }
        public string userid
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userid))
                {
                    _userid = this.getValue("userid");
                }
                return _userid;
            }
        }

        private string _fullname { get; set; }
        public string fullname
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fullname))
                {
                    _fullname = this.getValue("fullname");
                }
                return _fullname;
            }
        }

        private string _type { get; set; }
        public string type
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_type))
                {
                    _type = this.getValue("type");
                }
                return _type;
            }

        }

        private string _login { get; set; }
        public string login
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_login))
                {
                    _login = this.getValue("login");
                }
                return _login;
            }

        }

        private string _lastlogin { get; set; }
        public string lastlogin
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastlogin))
                {
                    _lastlogin = this.getValue("lastlogin");
                }
                return _lastlogin;
            }

        }

        private string _c1 { get; set; }
        public string c1
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c1))
                {
                    _c1 = this.getValue("c1");
                }
                return _c1;
            }

        }

        private string _c2 { get; set; }
        public string c2
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c2))
                {
                    _c2 = this.getValue("c2");
                }
                return _c2;
            }

        }

        private string _c3 { get; set; }
        public string c3
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c3))
                {
                    _c3 = this.getValue("c3");
                }
                return _c3;
            }

        }

        private string _c4 { get; set; }
        public string c4
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c4))
                {
                    _c4 = this.getValue("c4");
                }
                return _c4;
            }

        }

        private string _c5 { get; set; }
        public string c5
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c5))
                {
                    _c5 = this.getValue("c5");
                }
                return _c5;
            }

        }

        private string _c6 { get; set; }
        public string c6
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c6))
                {
                    _c6 = this.getValue("c6");
                }
                return _c6;
            }

        }

        private string _c7 { get; set; }
        public string c7
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c7))
                {
                    _c7 = this.getValue("c7");
                }
                return _c7;
            }

        }

        private string _c8 { get; set; }
        public string c8
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c8))
                {
                    _c8 = this.getValue("c8");
                }
                return _c8;
            }
        }


        private string _c9 { get; set; }
        public string c9
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c9))
                {
                    _c9 = this.getValue("c9");
                }
                return _c9;
            }
        }

        private string _c11 { get; set; }
        public string c11
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_c11))
                {
                    _c11 = this.getValue("c11");
                }
                return _c11;
            }
        }

        private string _ext { get; set; }
        public string ext
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ext))
                {
                    _ext = this.getValue("ext");
                }
                return _ext;
            }
        }

        private string _acl { get; set; }
        public string acl
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_acl))
                {
                    _acl = this.getValue("acl");
                }
                return _acl;
            }
        }
        public clsCookies()
        {
            this.session = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["session"] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["session"].Value : string.Empty;
        }
        private string getValue(string strCookie)
        {
            strCookie = string.Concat(this.session, strCookie);
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[strCookie] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[strCookie].Value : string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

- unless and untill i use system.web namespace in the page where
                 i have created object of this class i am unable to access 
                 the value of the property clientid please suggest a solution without making 
                 correction in the page which uses the object of this class is 
                 there a solution

Comment: what is the problem of using namespace? what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: clsCookies objClsCookies = new clsCookies();

Comment: what happens if you create object?

Comment: objClsCookies.clientid-unable to access this value in another page untill i am using system.web namespace

Comment: so use the namespace? why can't you use the namespace?

Comment: i have to apply the change in whole project its 4000+pages

Comment: if something is required, you have to add it; you add to the pages wherever you refer it

Comment: tell me the reason why i am not able to access the value